# MySql using IN() function to compare agains multiple items

Tags: mysql

Query:

```
SELECT (3,4) IN ((1,2,3), (4,5,6));
```

Result:

```
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 2 column(s)
```

Why is this not successful? How am I not understanding how `IN()` works?

My understanding is "Check to see if 3 and 4 is in the following sets of 1,2,3 and 4,5,6. If so return 1 else return 0"

Comment: I am happy with the answer below. The documentation of the `IN()` function was not comprehensive enough to answer my question. The answer lied elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare a ROW constructor consisting of 2 values versus ROW constructors consisting of 3 values. This is what gives you the error.

You should keep the same number of values like that:

```
SELECT (3,4) IN ((1,2), (4,5))
```

From [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-subqueries.html), **bold emphasis mine**:

> The expressions (1,2) and ROW(1,2) are sometimes called row constructors. The two are equivalent. **The row constructor and the row returned by the subquery must contain the same number of values**.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.